# Induce vibration on metal ball

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration, metals, lasers

Suppose that I have a hollow, metal ball that lies on a table.

How do I induce a vibration on this ball? I want to be able to control the frequency, so it is a forced vibration (not natural vibration).

I thought of using a [SASER](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_amplification_by_stimulated_emission_of_radiation) but I think those devices are rare.

Maybe a tuning fork could work, but then I can not control the frequency, because every tuning fork has only one frequency.

Could I use a periodic electromagnetic beam?

Comment: vibrate the table.

Comment: Sound, a gun, another ball, I mean come on there's a zillion alternatives. A hammer is typical.

Comment: Think about what you really mean when you say "electromagnetic beam" rather than some sci-fi thing. You are just saying light, or radio waves. Do any of those sound like they would work to you? I would think not. There is magneto-restriction, but that is going to need a tailored ball, among other difficulties...like an MRI probably. But it would seem magical. If a tuning fork would otherwise work, then yeah, just vibrate the table.

Comment: You can vary the frequency of a tuning fork by adding a mass that you adjust the position of...

Comment: `Maybe a tuning fork could work` ... what else generates a tone?

Comment: Just attach a powerful actuator to it that is capable of moving at the frequencies, rates, and forces you need, like the ones used for shaker tables...  Since you are forcing position over time, you must decide what position on your ball you are actually forcing and attach there.  Destruction of ball, table, or just downright overloading actuator are possibilities worth looking out for.